# lightning:inputField User lookup field get a user id value on the controller

Tags: lightning, lookup, inputfield

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordViewForm" onload="{!c.showRequiredFields}" recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="HolidayAction__c" onSubmit="{!c.clickCreate}"
    <lightning:messages/>
    <lightning:inputField class="customRequired none" aura:id="Pick_FirstHolidayRequest__c" fieldName="FirstHolidayRequest__c"/>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Hello!! this is soo new , there is no much useful tips on lightning:inputField tag...
above code is a user look up field value, originally it has used on custom lookup but after i changed inputField i can't get a user id value on the controller...how i can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is still an idea and not available 
see here.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dom1AAC.

To get more idea and alternative solution please see this

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005UKHQA2

```
Apex class

/**
 * @Author      :       Jitendra Zaa
 * @Date        :       4-Jul-2017
 * @Desc        :       Controller for Lookup Lightning Component
 * */
public class Lookup {

    /**
     * Returns JSON of list of ResultWrapper to Lex Components
     * @objectName - Name of SObject
     * @fld_API_Text - API name of field to display to user while searching
     * @fld_API_Val - API name of field to be returned by Lookup COmponent
     * @lim   - Total number of record to be returned
     * @fld_API_Search - API name of field to be searched
     * @searchText - text to be searched
     * */
    @AuraEnabled 
    public static String searchDB(String objectName, String fld_API_Text, String fld_API_Val, 
                                  Integer lim,String fld_API_Search,String searchText ){

        searchText='\'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchText.trim()) + '%\'';


        String query = 'SELECT '+fld_API_Text+' ,'+fld_API_Val+
                        ' FROM '+objectName+
                            ' WHERE '+fld_API_Search+' LIKE '+searchText+ 
                        ' LIMIT '+lim;

        List<sObject> sobjList = Database.query(query);
        List<ResultWrapper> lstRet = new List<ResultWrapper>();

        for(SObject s : sobjList){
            ResultWrapper obj = new ResultWrapper();
            obj.objName = objectName;
            obj.text = String.valueOf(s.get(fld_API_Text)) ;
            obj.val = String.valueOf(s.get(fld_API_Val))  ;
            lstRet.add(obj);
        } 
         return JSON.serialize(lstRet) ;
    }

    public class ResultWrapper{
        public String objName {get;set;}
        public String text{get;set;}
        public String val{get;set;}
    }
}


Component 

<aura:component controller="Lookup"> 
     <aura:attribute Name="selItem" type="object" access="public" 
                     description="This attribute can be used by parent component to read selected record"/>  
     <aura:attribute Name="server_result" type="object[]" access="private" /> 

     <aura:attribute name="lookupIcon" type="String" access="public" default="standard:contact"/>

    <aura:attribute name="objectName" type="String" access="public" 
                    description="Name of Object to be searched"/>
    <aura:attribute name="field_API_text" type="String" access="public" 
                    description="API Name of field, to be used to show text"/>
    <aura:attribute name="field_API_val" type="String" access="public" 
                    description="API Name of field, to be returned from component"/>
    <aura:attribute name="field_API_search" type="String" access="public" 
                    description="API Name of field to be searched"/>
    <aura:attribute name="limit" type="Integer" access="public" default="5" 
                    description="Total number of record to be returned"/>
    <aura:attribute name="placeholder" type="String" access="public" 
                    default="Space character is used to search" />

    <aura:attribute name="last_SearchText" type="String" access="private" />
    <aura:attribute name="last_ServerResult" type="object[]" access="private" /> 

    <div class="slds">      
        <div class="slds-form-element"> 
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <div class="slds-combobox_container slds-has-inline-listbox">
                    <div class="slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open" 
                         aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox" style="width:95%">
                        <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
                            <div> 
                                <aura:if isTrue="{! empty(v.selItem) }"> 
                                         <input type="text" class="slds-input slds-combobox__input" id="combobox-unique-id" 
                                                aria-activedescendant="listbox-option-unique-id-01" aria-autocomplete="list" 
                                                aria-controls="listbox-unique-id" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" 
                                                placeholder="{!v.placeholder}" 
                                                onkeyup="{!c.serverCall}" />
                                        <aura:set attribute="else"> 
                                                <span class="slds-pill slds-pill_link fullWidth"> 
                                                  <a href="javascript:void(0);" 
                                                     class="slds-pill__action slds-p-left_x-small" title="{#v.selItem.text}">
                                                    <lightning:icon iconName="{#v.lookupIcon}" size="x-small"/>
                                                    <span class="slds-pill__label slds-p-left_x-small">{#v.selItem.text}</span>
                                                  </a>
                                                  <button onclick="{!c.clearSelection}" 
                                                          class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon slds-pill__remove" 
                                                          title="Remove">
                                                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:close" size="small" 
                                                                    alternativeText="Press delete or backspace to remove"/>
                                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text" >Remove</span>
                                                  </button>
                                                </span> 
                                        </aura:set>
                                    </aura:if> 
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <aura:if isTrue="{! greaterthanorequal(v.server_result.length,1) }"> 
                                <div id="listbox-unique-id" role="listbox">
                                    <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_fluid" role="presentation"
                                        style="display: block; min-width: auto; max-width: 100% ; width: 100%;">
                                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.server_result}" var="item" indexVar="i">
                                            <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item" data-selectedIndex="{#i}" 
                                                onclick="{!c.itemSelected}">
                                                <span id="{#'listbox-option-unique-id-'+i+1}"  
                                                      class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity 
                                                             slds-listbox__option_has-meta" 
                                                      role="option">
                                                    <span class="slds-media__figure optionIcon">
                                                        <span class="slds-icon_container" >
                                                            <lightning:icon iconName="{#v.lookupIcon}" size="small"/>
                                                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">{#v.objectName}</span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                    <span class="slds-media__body singleRow">
                                                        <span 
                                                              class="optionTitle slds-listbox__option-text 
                                                                     slds-listbox__option-text_entity">{#item.text}</span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </span>
                                            </li>
                                        </aura:iteration> 
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </aura:if> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
    </div>     
</aura:component>

CSS

    .THIS{
        width:99%;
    }
    .THIS .fullWidth{
        width:100%;
    }
    .THIS .slds-listbox__item:hover {
        background: #d8edff;
        text-shadow: none;
        color: #16325c;
    }

    .THIS .optionParent1{
        line-height: 1.5;
        padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
        font-size: 0.8125rem;
    }

    .THIS .optionIcon {
       margin-top: 0.50rem;
    }

    .THIS .optionTitle{
            max-width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 0.125rem;
    }

    .THIS .optionline{
            display: block;
        margin-top: -0.25rem;
        color: #54698d;
    }
    .THIS .singleRow{
        padding-top:5px;
    }

    .THIS .hide{
        display:none;
    }



JS controller 

({
    itemSelected : function(component, event, helper) {
        var target = event.target;   
        var SelIndex = helper.getIndexFrmParent(target,helper,"data-selectedIndex");  
        if(SelIndex){
            var serverResult = component.get("v.server_result");
            var selItem = serverResult[SelIndex];
            if(selItem.val){
               component.set("v.selItem",selItem);
               component.set("v.last_ServerResult",serverResult);
            } 
            component.set("v.server_result",null); 
        } 
    }, 
    serverCall : function(component, event, helper) {  
        var target = event.target;  
        var searchText = target.value; 
        var last_SearchText = component.get("v.last_SearchText");
        //Escape button pressed 
        if (event.keyCode == 27 || !searchText.trim()) { 
            helper.clearSelection(component, event, helper);
        }else if(searchText.trim() != last_SearchText  && /\s+$/.test(searchText) ){ 
            //Save server call, if last text not changed
            //Search only when space character entered

            var objectName = component.get("v.objectName");
            var field_API_text = component.get("v.field_API_text");
            var field_API_val = component.get("v.field_API_val");
            var field_API_search = component.get("v.field_API_search");
            var limit = component.get("v.limit");

            var action = component.get('c.searchDB');
            action.setStorable();

            action.setParams({
                objectName : objectName,
                fld_API_Text : field_API_text,
                fld_API_Val : field_API_val,
                lim : limit, 
                fld_API_Search : field_API_search,
                searchText : searchText
            });

            action.setCallback(this,function(a){
                this.handleResponse(a,component,helper);
            });

            component.set("v.last_SearchText",searchText.trim());
            console.log('Server call made');
            $A.enqueueAction(action); 
        }else if(searchText && last_SearchText && searchText.trim() == last_SearchText.trim()){ 
            component.set("v.server_result",component.get("v.last_ServerResult"));
            console.log('Server call saved');
        }         
    },
    handleResponse : function (res,component,helper){
        if (res.getState() === 'SUCCESS') {
            var retObj = JSON.parse(res.getReturnValue());
            if(retObj.length <= 0){
                var noResult = JSON.parse('[{"text":"No Results Found"}]');
                component.set("v.server_result",noResult); 
                component.set("v.last_ServerResult",noResult);
            }else{
                component.set("v.server_result",retObj); 
                component.set("v.last_ServerResult",retObj);
            }  
        }else if (res.getState() === 'ERROR'){
            var errors = res.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    alert(errors[0].message);
                }
            } 
        }
    },
    getIndexFrmParent : function(target,helper,attributeToFind){
        //User can click on any child element, so traverse till intended parent found
        var SelIndex = target.getAttribute(attributeToFind);
        while(!SelIndex){
            target = target.parentNode ;
            SelIndex = helper.getIndexFrmParent(target,helper,attributeToFind);           
        }
        return SelIndex;
    },
    clearSelection: function(component, event, helper){
        component.set("v.selItem",null);
        component.set("v.server_result",null);
    } 
})


Helper 

({
    itemSelected : function(component, event, helper) {
        var target = event.target;   
        var SelIndex = helper.getIndexFrmParent(target,helper,"data-selectedIndex");  
        if(SelIndex){
            var serverResult = component.get("v.server_result");
            var selItem = serverResult[SelIndex];
            if(selItem.val){
               component.set("v.selItem",selItem);
               component.set("v.last_ServerResult",serverResult);
            } 
            component.set("v.server_result",null); 
        } 
    }, 
    serverCall : function(component, event, helper) {  
        var target = event.target;  
        var searchText = target.value; 
        var last_SearchText = component.get("v.last_SearchText");
        //Escape button pressed 
        if (event.keyCode == 27 || !searchText.trim()) { 
            helper.clearSelection(component, event, helper);
        }else if(searchText.trim() != last_SearchText  && /\s+$/.test(searchText) ){ 
            //Save server call, if last text not changed
            //Search only when space character entered

            var objectName = component.get("v.objectName");
            var field_API_text = component.get("v.field_API_text");
            var field_API_val = component.get("v.field_API_val");
            var field_API_search = component.get("v.field_API_search");
            var limit = component.get("v.limit");

            var action = component.get('c.searchDB');
            action.setStorable();

            action.setParams({
                objectName : objectName,
                fld_API_Text : field_API_text,
                fld_API_Val : field_API_val,
                lim : limit, 
                fld_API_Search : field_API_search,
                searchText : searchText
            });

            action.setCallback(this,function(a){
                this.handleResponse(a,component,helper);
            });

            component.set("v.last_SearchText",searchText.trim());
            console.log('Server call made');
            $A.enqueueAction(action); 
        }else if(searchText && last_SearchText && searchText.trim() == last_SearchText.trim()){ 
            component.set("v.server_result",component.get("v.last_ServerResult"));
            console.log('Server call saved');
        }         
    },
    handleResponse : function (res,component,helper){
        if (res.getState() === 'SUCCESS') {
            var retObj = JSON.parse(res.getReturnValue());
            if(retObj.length <= 0){
                var noResult = JSON.parse('[{"text":"No Results Found"}]');
                component.set("v.server_result",noResult); 
                component.set("v.last_ServerResult",noResult);
            }else{
                component.set("v.server_result",retObj); 
                component.set("v.last_ServerResult",retObj);
            }  
        }else if (res.getState() === 'ERROR'){
            var errors = res.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    alert(errors[0].message);
                }
            } 
        }
    },
    getIndexFrmParent : function(target,helper,attributeToFind){
        //User can click on any child element, so traverse till intended parent found
        var SelIndex = target.getAttribute(attributeToFind);
        while(!SelIndex){
            target = target.parentNode ;
            SelIndex = helper.getIndexFrmParent(target,helper,attributeToFind);           
        }
        return SelIndex;
    },
    clearSelection: function(component, event, helper){
        component.set("v.selItem",null);
        component.set("v.server_result",null);
    } 
})
```

The component

```
            <aura:if isTrue="{! not(empty(v.selItem)) }"> 
                <br />
                This is Parent Lightning component <br />
                Item Selected : <br />
                ID - {#v.selItem.val} <br /> 
                Text - {#v.selItem.text}<br />
                Object - {#v.selItem.objName}
            </aura:if> 
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-1 
                    slds-small-size_1-of-1 
                    slds-medium-size_1-of-2 
                    slds-large-size_1-of-4 ">
            <c:Lookup objectName="Lead"
                      field_API_text="Name"
                      field_API_val="Id"
                      limit="4"
                      field_API_search="Name"
                      lookupIcon="standard:lead" 
                      selItem="{!v.selItem1}"
                      placeholder="Enter space after text to search Leads
                                   "/>  

            <aura:if isTrue="{! not(empty(v.selItem1)) }"> 
                <br />
                This is Parent Lightning component <br />
                Item Selected : <br />
                ID - {#v.selItem1.val} <br /> 
                Text - {#v.selItem1.text}<br />
                Object - {#v.selItem1.objName}
            </aura:if> 
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-1 
                    slds-small-size_1-of-1 
                    slds-medium-size_1-of-2 
                    slds-large-size_1-of-4 ">
            <c:Lookup objectName="Account"
                      field_API_text="Name"
                      field_API_val="Id"
                      limit="4"
                      field_API_search="Name"
                      lookupIcon="standard:account" 
                      selItem="{!v.selItem2}" 
                      placeholder="Enter space after text to search Accounts"
                      />  

            <aura:if isTrue="{! not(empty(v.selItem2)) }"> 
                <br />
                This is Parent Lightning component <br />
                Item Selected : <br />
                ID - {#v.selItem2.val} <br /> 
                Text - {#v.selItem2.text}<br />
                Object - {#v.selItem2.objName}
            </aura:if> 
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-1 
                    slds-small-size_1-of-1 
                    slds-medium-size_1-of-2 
                    slds-large-size_1-of-4 ">
            <c:Lookup objectName="Contact"
                      field_API_text="Name"
                      field_API_val="Id"
                      limit="4" 
                      field_API_search="Name"
                      lookupIcon="standard:contact" 
                      selItem="{!v.selItem3}"
                      placeholder="Enter space after text to search Contacts"
                      />  

            <aura:if isTrue="{! not(empty(v.selItem3)) }"> 
                <br />
                This is Parent Lightning component <br />
                Item Selected : <br />
                ID - {#v.selItem3.val} <br /> 
                Text - {#v.selItem3.text}<br />
                Object - {#v.selItem3.objName}
            </aura:if> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest that you add some details from "alternative solution" link here. So if in case linked post get deleted your answer remain valid.